# Laravel Lumen ReflectionException

Tags: laravel, api, routes, request, lumen

I already had a look at other post about how to fix the **ReflectionException** issue in laravel Lumen, using this:

```
 $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
 $app->run($request);
```

However it is not solving my problem. I have a controller called AccountController.php and placed in app/Http/Controllers/Account folder and here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Account;

use App\Account;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AccountController extends Controller {

public function createNewAccount(Request $request) {
    $newAccount = Account::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($newAccount);
    }
}
```

And this is my route file placed in /routes/web.php:

```
<?php

$app->get('/hello', function () use ($app) {
    return 'Hello World!';
});


$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1','namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Account'], function($app)
{
    $app->post('account','AccountController@createNewAccount');
});
```

When I test with Postman the get request which returns a simple 'Hello World' is working fine, but the POST call to **api/v1/account/createNewAccount** will always fail whatever I do:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 681:
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Account\AccountController does not exist
>   in Container.php line 681
>   at ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Account\AccountController') in Container.php line 681
>   at Container->build('App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Account\AccountController') in Container.php line 565
>   at Container->make('App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Account\AccountController') in Application.php line 208
>   at Application->make('App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Account\AccountController') in RoutesRequests.php line 677
>   at Application->callControllerAction(array(true, array('uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Account\AccountController@createNewAccount'), array())) in RoutesRequests.php line 644
>   at Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array(true, array('uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Account\AccountController@createNewAccount'), array())) in RoutesRequests.php line 629
>   at Application->handleFoundRoute(array(true, array('uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Account\AccountController@createNewAccount'), array())) in RoutesRequests.php line 528
>   at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns{closure}() in RoutesRequests.php line 782
>   at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 534
>   at Application->dispatch(object(Request)) in RoutesRequests.php line 475
>   at Application->run(object(Request)) in index.php line 29

I am using "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.4.*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reply to this particular issue, I decided to build my API with Dingo API: https://github.com/dingo/api It is a good package to build API with Laravel/lumen. They created their own routing system and things are going much better since.